# Navigation bar active class not working correctly when route to another link

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

How do I set active class when a link is clicked? 
The Link1 does not get the active class when it is clicked.
The codes are given below:
HTML Part:

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="nav">
        <li id="home" class="active"><a href="/Home/Index">Home</a></li>
        <li id="skill"><a href="/Home/GoToLink1">Link1</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

I have also used JQuery:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#nav li a').on('click', function () {
        $(this).parent().parent().find('.active').removeClass('active');
        $(this).parent().addClass('active');
    });
});
</script>
```

When I clicked any link, the active property not works correctly.

Comment: Pretty simple... there is no state saving persistence when you load a new page. You need to check href when page loads or set the class at server

Comment: Thanks for this valuable information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you redirect to new page dynamic state are not preserved. Get current location and then iterate through the `nav` menus. Which link is matched with current location make that `active` like below. Hope it helps.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var location = window.location.href;
        $('#nav li a').each(function(){
            if(location.indexOf(this.href)>-1) {
               $(this).parent().addClass('active');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```